# How to properly pass and check multiple values in array in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the permissions of the user in the active session with the `check_users_permissions` function, and then I try to `echo "Access granted";` if there are `permissionID: "1"` and `permissionName: "Access users"` among the permissions the user has.

But I couldn't find exactly how to do it in `check_users permissions`, which is the function to check the users permissions in the array.

I always get the following errors in the methods I try:
*Trying to access array offset on value of type null* or
*Undefined index: permissionName*

I'm not entirely sure if my method of transferring the user's permissions to the session is wrong or not.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my User Class php:**

```
<?php

Class User {

    private function get_user_hash($username)
    {
        try {
            if ($this->_ignoreCase) {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT userID, userRoleID, password, email, tfaSwitch, tfaCode, username FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(:username) AND activasionCode="Completed" ');
            } else {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT userID, userRoleID, password, email, tfaSwitch, tfaCode, username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND activasionCode="Completed" ');
            }
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        }
    }

    public function get_user_permissions($username)
    {
        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT roleID, permissionID, permissionName FROM roles_permissions WHERE roleID = :userRoleID");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'userRoleID' => $row['userRoleID']
            ));
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        $permissions = $this->get_user_permissions($username);

        if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $row['tfaSwitch'] == "Off") {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['userRoleID'] = $row['userRoleID'];
            $_SESSION['permissions'] = $permissions;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function check_users_permissions($permissionID, $permissionName)
    {
        return in_array($_SESSION['permissions'][$permissionID], $_SESSION['permissions'][$permissionName]);
    }
}
?>
```

**Here is my index.php**

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');

if (! $user->is_logged_in() ){ 
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    exit(); 
}

if (! $user->check_users_permissions(1, "Access users")) {    
    echo 'Access Denied!';
}
else {
    echo 'Access Granted';    
}

?>
```

**Here is the `var_dump($_SESSION['permissions']);`**

```
array(4) { 
    
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["roleID"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["permissionID"]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) ["permissionName"]=> string(12) "Access users" [2]=> string(12) "Access users" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(6) { 
        ["roleID"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["permissionID"]=> int(2) [1]=> int(2) ["permissionName"]=> string(16) "Create new users" [2]=> string(16) "Create new users" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(6) { 
        ["roleID"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["permissionID"]=> int(3) [1]=> int(3) ["permissionName"]=> string(12) "Update users" [2]=> string(12) "Update users" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(6) { 
        ["roleID"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["permissionID"]=> int(4) [1]=> int(4) ["permissionName"]=> string(12) "Delete users" [2]=> string(12) "Delete users" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($permissions)` in `login` ?

Comment: I just updated the question and showed it there. @AntG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to navigate your `$permissions` array, you need to loop through it looking for the relevant settings:

```php
    public function check_users_permissions($permissionID, $permissionName)
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['permissions'] AS $entry){
             if(
                isset($entry['permissionID']) && isset($entry['permissionName']
                && $entry['permissionID']===$permissionID
                && $entry['permissionName']===$permissionName
              )
              {
                 return true;
              }
         }
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: It works thank you. I thought it wouldn't be appropriate to control this with `foreach`, and I couldn't find the logic to do it with `foreach`. But I think this is the most convenient way.